# Downloading and installing APK

Tags: java, pthreads, android

I made code that download APK from ftp, and I`m trying to install it after download. I wrote this for Honeycomb, so in every connection i have to use threads. How can I use startActivity in class within thread, or wait for thread to finish?

```
public class FTPapkDowload {
protected static final String TAG = "Tablet Development";
public FTPClient mFTPClient = null;
public FTPClient mFtp = null;

public void Start() {

Thread apkdowload = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            ftpConnect("mysite", "username", "password",21);
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected");
            ftpDownload("/httpdocs/Shamir/app.apk", "sdcard/Download/app.apk");
            ftpDisconnect();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            startActivity(intent); //Here is the problem


        }

        //Connection
        public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username,
                String password, int port) {
            try {

                mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
                mFTPClient.connect(host, port); 

                if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {
                    boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);

                    mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                    mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    return status;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not connect to host " + host);
            }

            return false;
        }


        //Downloading
        public boolean ftpDownload(String srcFilePath, String desFilePath) {
            boolean status = false;
            try {

                FileOutputStream desFileStream = new FileOutputStream(
                        desFilePath);
                status = mFTPClient
                        .retrieveFile(srcFilePath, desFileStream);
                desFileStream.close();
                return status;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "download failed");
            }

            return status;
        }



        public boolean ftpDisconnect() {

            try {
                mFTPClient.logout();
                mFTPClient.disconnect();
                Log.d(TAG, "Disconected from FTP on apk Download");

                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Error occurred while disconnecting from ftp server on apk download.");
            }

            return false;
        }

    });

    apkdowload.start();
}
```

}

Comment: Please give people credit for their effort to help you and [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/164138) on your previous questions. You haven't accepted a single answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a handler:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {

        }
    };
```

When your thread is done running the code it needs to call: `handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);`

More info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: Or you can create the handler on the UI thread, and then within the worker thread, call `handler.post(new Runnable(){...});`. This is how I like to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this is for your FTP download code to notify your main thread that it has finished, and make the main (UI) thread call startActivity. You can do this using any number of methods for communication between threads, for example a Handler:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Or simply Activity.runOnUiThread:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

A good read is the "Painless Threading" blog post:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to pass context of your activity to the class in which you want to use activity's methods.

Answer (score 0):

To execute UI methods you have run this on UI Thread:

Put this inside your normal Threads run() Method:

```
       YourClass.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {

               startyourActivity();
           }
       });
```